# How to change kendo jquery version

Tags: kendo-ui

I am including the following files in my layout:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After doing some research I found that the only way to fix a bug with the kendo window in older versions of IE when using jquery 1.8 is to use jquery version 1.7.2 because this is a stable version.

How do I go about downloading and updating the kendo jquery file to 1.7.2?  I'm not even sure what version of jquery the kendo file currently is using because the name is just "jquery.min.js". I'm assuming jquery 1.8 because I am experiencing the bug.

Answer (score 1):

What they say in their [web site](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#jquery-version) is:

**jQuery version**

The current official version of Kendo UI requires jQuery 1.9.1. There are occasions in which a new jQuery version is released, which introduces breaking changes and is not compatible with existing Kendo UI versions. In such cases we recommend using the previous jQuery version until the next official Kendo UI release that resolves the problems. We normally do not change the jQuery version that is shipped with Kendo UI for service packs. We can do this for major releases. The following list provides compatibility information about previous major Kendo UI releases:

- Kendo UI 2013.1.319 (Q2 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1
- Kendo UI 2013.1.319 (Q1 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1
- Kendo UI 2012.3.1114 (Q3 2012) - jQuery 1.8.2
- Kendo UI 2012.2.710 (Q2 2012) - jQuery 1.7.1
- Kendo UI 2012.1.322 (Q1 2012) - jQuery 1.7.1
- Kendo UI 2011.3.1129 (Q3 2011) - jQuery 1.7.1

There should be no problem to use another minor jQuery version instead of the specified above, e.g. 1.7.2 instead of 1.7.1.

Comment: Another way to ask this question is if I wanted to change the version of my kendo jquery file how would I do this? I know you can download different versions of jquery from the jquery website and I could be wrong on this but i thought i needed to download kendos version of jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: Kendo UI people do not change jQuery files so you are free from getting it from jQuery site. What they do is testing KendoUI with one specific version of jQuery. If you try it with other version you might find some errors -or not-. So the answer would be get it from http://jquery.com/ and try it.

Comment: BTW: you might check which version of jquery is Kendo UI distributing opening jquery.min.js and in the first line you should see something like. `/*! jQuery v1.9.1 | (c) 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license`